# Maven publish & consume the third-party runtime jars while building our own custom.jar

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-management

I've a maven project for which we are loading internal `abc-1.0.jar` using S3 repository and whatever  runtime dependencies requires for `abc-1.0.jar` to be a part of my project, we load in the form of `.zip` and extract it as

**Interesting Note:** When I say third-party runtime jars as a zip, there are some jars which might not have used while building `abc-1.0.jar`

```
project.zip
 -- lib
    -- abc-1.0.jar
    -- runtime_jars_for_abc.jar
    -- runtime_jars_for_project.jar
```

There is possibility that when deliver `abc-1.0.jar` jar to `my-project` the runtime zip might have `one set of jars` but for `abc-2.0.jar` I need to ship `another set of jars`.

I've solved the problem by shipping it in the form of zip and extracting it while creating the `project.zip`

But, is it possible that I can ship or announce those `runtime.jar` along with my `abc-1.0.jar` or `abc-2.0.jar` so that `my-project/pom.xml` can consume that announcement on the fly from either `mavenCentral()` or my internal `maven-repo`?

**EDIT**

I found `maven changes plugin` here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/. this is mostly going to publish the new changes but how can I dynamically consume the new changes for each new build? any thoughts?

**What I was thinking is to push the `abc-1.0.jar` along with it's `abc-1.0-pom.xml` file which should consist of some custom scope or logical grouping of dependent jar, so that I can specify those `custom scopes` or `groups` in consumption project to uniquely copy those jars using `maven copy dependencies plugin` https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html* but unfortunately maven doesn't support `custom scopes`

Comment: i'm far away to be sure that i understand your question, if i rephrase: project A has a dependency with project B, what should i do to get project B'updates in project A ?

Comment: OK.. Lemme try.. `project-B` which is dependency of `project-A` needs some runtime jars. What we do right now is add `project-B-1.0.jar` as a maven dependency in `project-A` and ship `set_of_run_time.jar` as well to `project-A`. It might possible that `project-B-2.0.jar` would need `different_versioned_set_of_run_time.jar` to be shipped in `project-A`

I suppose to `announce` those runtime jars while building  `project-B-1.0/2.0.jar` so that `project-A` can consume those. hope, it clarifies

Comment: Why not make sure, that the `project-B` upgrades version according to its dependency upgrade? The concept of the dynamic load is slightly flawed in the question as it is phrased but.

Comment: `abc-1.0.jar` might need 100s of jars as a runtime and I need those to be copied using `maven copy dependencies` plugin to my final project `lib` folder

Answer (score 1):

In your project-b, prefix your version by **-SNAPSHOT**, like this

```
<groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
<artifactId>my.artifactid</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

So, every time when you do update in your project-b,  your project-a will pick the latest snapshot from maven repository

As you can see, maven organize snapshot by adding a timestamp to deliver the latest publish

[image]

Note that your project-a must never go to acceptance, pprod or production environment with snapshot dependencies !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It might possible that `project-B` which is shipping the `zip` of runtime jars has not used it for compilation.. so it would be difficult that `project-A` can get it as a `transitive dependency`